# Img oversize on ios

Tags: android, css, ios, windows, macos

Hello Im working on a project on a wedding wesite but I have an issue with the image in the footer.
Its a Svg in an  tag. Its the same as the one in the Nav but does not seam to work the same.
On Windows and Android, Its all good but on iOS it just go way bigger than its supposed to.
[mariage-elise-thaddee.be](https://mariage-elise-thaddee.be)

I changed the extension of the image but did not change anything.
I box-sizing:border-box to make sure it does see the full size of the element but didint work either.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid there is no way we can help without seeing relevant code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may like to use caniuse.com to check that all the CSS you are using is supported (for example, are you using background-attachment?)

Comment: Have you checked the online source of that site? It has misplaced `<script>` insertions at the top. Should be inside `<head>` or at the bottom, just before `</body>`. Correct that first.

Answer (score 0):

based on the details you provided, which were not that many, I would suggest using 'webkit' extensions on your commands and check if it makes a difference. If it does not please come back with more details and I will try to help you if I can

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).